# NFQUEUE/IPtables - Suricata Inline With Python Intercept for DNS

Tags: python, linux, iptables

Here is what I am trying to achieve. I have an inline linux box running Suricata capable of dropping packets. This works with the standard method of placing all traffic onto NFQUEUE 0 and then setting suricata listening on that.

The code I am writing needs to be able to intercept DNS and Kerberos packets on NFQUEUE 1, but it still needs to be scanned inline with Suricata, so the packet needs to be passed back to another NFQUEUE that suricata is listening on because I don't think both programs can act as a consumer on the same queue.

So far I have worked out how to chop out DNS and Kerberos traffic to a different NFQueue, so suricata listens on NFQUEUE 1 and my program listens on NFQUEUE 2, what I need is a way to use iptables to put traffic from one NFQUEUE onto another.

Something like this:

iptables -I NFQUEUE --queue-num 1 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 2

There is probably something with post routing that I am missing, (Something like outbound packets that match my origional DNS/Kerboros rules being placed on to the NFqueue, but this will created a loop when I tested it)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways to do it:

You can edit suricata.yaml and under `nfq:`, set the `mode: route` and `route-queue` to the corresponding DNS/Kerberos queue. This will pass on the packets after Suricata finishes with them.

OR

Mark the packet and queue to Suricata on 1 (i.e. `-m mark ! --mark 0x1/0x1 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1`).

Next, those packets that weren't dropped by Suricata are returned to the chain and move to the next rule where you can queue to DNS/Kerberos on 2.

In suricata.yaml, you'll need to edit nfq:

```
mode: repeat
  repeat-mark: 1
  repeat-mask: 1
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

From the networking I've done, you'll need to put the 2 NFQUEUE commands into different table/chain tuples, eg. one in filter/FORWARD and the other in mangle/PREROUTING. Basically, once a packet has gone to a single NFQUEUE in a table/chain combo, it's done for that table/chain and it exits the main chain entirely. My personal recommendation is to put your NFQUEUE into mangle/PREROUTING, which will be called before most of the other tables (assuming you're putting the Suricata NFQUEUE statement into the filter table).

I hope this makes sense. Hope it helps!